# VBA Moving negative value to next cell and adding total

Tags: vba, excel

The macro should shift a negative value to the cell to the right and make it positive.
And if there is already a value in the cell on the right the macro should add them together.

I can do the first step with the code below.

```
Sub tested()    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lrow As Integer
    Dim nextcell As Long

    With ActiveSheet
    lrow = .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        
        For Each rng In .Range("L3:L" & lrow)    
           If rng.Value < 0 Then    
             rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = Abs(rng.Value)
             rng.Value = ""
           End If    
        Next rng    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = Abs(rng.Value) + rng.Offset(0,-1).Value` ? Or where is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

"shift a negative value to the cell to the right" means `rng.Offset(0, 1)` and not `rng.Offset(0, -1)`

So you may try something like this...

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lrow As Long

With ActiveSheet
lrow = .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each rng In .Range("L3:L" & lrow)
        If rng.Value < 0 Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value + Abs(rng.Value)
            rng.Value = ""
        End If
    Next rng
End With
```

Comment: Given that you've already learned `rng.Value < 0`, you can avoid a call to `Abs` and just use `rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value - rng.Value`

Comment: You are right, that's another approach to write that syntax. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub tested()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lrow As Integer
    Dim nextcell As Long
    With ActiveSheet
    lrow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each rng In .Range("B1:B" & lrow)
            If rng.Value < 0 Then
                If IsNumeric(rng.Offset(0, -1).Value) Then
                    rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = rng.Offset(0, -1).Value + Abs(rng.Value)
                Else
                    rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = Abs(rng.Value)
                End If
                rng.Value = ""
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```